PDE of a convolution
Suppose that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are two functions defined on $\mathbb{R}\times(0,+\infty)$ and satisfy:
$$\mathcal{L}_1 f_1 = 0\quad\mathrm{and} \quad\mathcal{L}_2 f_2 = 0$$
where $\mathcal{L}_1$ and $\mathcal{L}_2$ are two linear operators. Does the convolution in space $f_1*f_2$ defined as:
$$\quad (f_1*f_2)(x,t) = \int_\mathbb{R}f_1(x-y,t)f_2(y,t)dy$$
satisfy another explicit PDE ?
Thank you very much!

If $\mathcal{L}_1$ and the integral are interchangeable, then $\mathcal{L}_1(f_1*f_2)(x, t) = 0$

Thank you @HyperbolicPDEfriend!

Just for clarity: $\mathcal{L}_1$ and $\mathcal{L}_2$ are differential operators, right?

Yes, they are typically differential operators of order 1 and 2 w.r.t. time and space variables
